# Tell Rails to only update blank or nil values vs. complete API object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, controller, updates

When grabbing a complete object from an API, and putting some of its values into a Model in Rails, how do I tell Rails to only update the Model fields that are still empty/nil?

Say there are 10 total values coming in from the API and I want six for the Model, but some records already have 4 filled in. How do I tell Rails to fill in just the two blank ones, and leave the existing ones alone?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is a method to do this, but you can do it this way, get a list of attributes that have a nil value

`update_list = model_object.as_json.except(*model_object.attributes.keys)`

and change the values in the `update_list` and do a normal update `model_object.update_attributes(update_list)`

you could pass a `validate: false` if you get any validation error and if you can skip them or you can iterate through the `update_list` and use `update_attribute` instead.

Comment: An interesting start @Subash…but…in that approach, where do we map the API fields onto the Model fields? (Let's say the API field is called "customer" and the Model field is called "customer_name"…).

Comment: @MatthewBennett It depends on your requirement, but helper methods or even a mapping module could be a good place